# Why would GLFW be calling the key callback function for a couple seconds after releasing key?

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm currently working on a Vulkan application, along with GLFW and I just did a pretty big refactor. However, when I now press on any key for a long amount of time (e.g. 3 seconds) the key callback function gets called for a couple seconds even after releasing the key (the amount of time it gets called after release seems to be proportional to the amount of time I pressed the key). When running the application before the refactor (original codebase) this doesn't happen.

I know that there isn't much context with which you can infer information from, but has anyone ever experienced this weirdness?

I've narrowed the problem down to the execution of a graphics pipeline but I have no clue how this could possibly affect the input handling of GLFW??

Any help would be so so appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `glfwPollEvents()` to correctly poll events as fast as possible? You're not doing any squirrelly sleeps between frames or anything, right?

Comment: Specifically since you mentioned Vulkan, try to see if the issue resolves itself if you use mailbox presenting (and if your device doesn't support it, go on a computer that does for this test).

Comment: Alright - so I found the issue and it makes a *bit* more sense: ImGUI. When I don't render the ImGUI window, the weird input thing happens. When I do render it, the bug doesn't happen. I will definitely have to step into ImGUI code to see why this happens though...